# What are good resources for animating and displaying 3d objects in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

An example of such an animation would be a dice rolling ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/) or [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Know any good samples for Balder?  Or blog entries?  I'd like to learn some more without downloading anything or changing my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how you could do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500570.aspx).  Quote:

> a little educational application
>   demonstrating how various 3D shapes
>   (called polyhedra) can be assembled by
>   folding a flat template